# Product has image but it show placeholder image as default image

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, product-images, importexport, placeholder

I got a strange problem I imported products by csv. There're some products showing placeholder magento image, even it has image.

I try to re save, reindex, clear cache. not working it still showing. here's my website:

https://www.dcctoyou.com/index.php/--12997.html

I notice that all product showing placeholder image it can't set status disableand. I mean, it alway show on front even status is disabled.

Only one thing I can do if I want this product to hide on front. I need to uncheck main website store view, then i disappear.

Anyone has experience on this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: have you set base image, small image & thumbnail image for that product?

Comment: Yes , I had set all of them

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have uploaded image and when I click on that image in frontend it does show up.

Which means you haven't set it up to show up from `catalog edit > images` section.

Set your image as `small image`, `base image` and `thumb image` in `images` section of your catalog page.

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to **fschmengler** for pointing this, I totally missed it.

> Please make sure that the image settings are not overridden in store
>   view scope. Status could have been overridden there as well.

Good luck

Comment: I had set all thing correctly and yes I already upload image. but it show placeholder.

Comment: Please make sure that the image settings are not overridden in store view scope. Status could have been overridden there as well.

Comment: Thanks Fschmengler !!!, i miss it. some store set no image as default :). thanks to remind me.

Comment: and it is also wise to check the permissions for media folder